# How to make a video list youtube-like in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a youtube-like application for desktop. I've got a database with videos in it and I've got my search function implemented. The thing is that I don't know how to make the interface display the list of videos so that I can then click on one and play it. I wanted to know if there's a GUI element that I can use to add several entries to it and display them as youtube displays the videos from your suscriptions as a list.

I'm new to user interface, so sorry in advance for the noob question.

Comment: If you need help with UI design you should make a mockup that shows what you want to get.

Comment: An obvious choice for the list of videos is to use a `JList`.

Answer (score 2):

### JPanels and FlowLayout, that's it...

Create and `JPanel`, representing one video, let's call them **video containers**, it has `JLabel` for the title, views and author. You make one of those JPanels for every video, those have to be small, such as those in YouTube. Now to arrange those, the trick is, that the `JPanel`, where you want those video containers to be, has to be the same width, or little bit bigger than the video containers, and use `FlowLayout`. With the fixed width and `FlowLayout`, your video containers will be stacked under each other, vertically, just like in YouTube on the right hand side of the display.

### Demo

Note I used BoxLayout with Y_AXIS to stack the videos not the FlowLayout method. It works, check it out :D

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class YoutubeLikeUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0,0));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

        // This is the part than you're interested in
        // Adding video to the panel
        JPanel videos = new JPanel();
        // Important, make videos stack under each other / vertically
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(videos, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        videos.setLayout(layout);
        // Here we are adding the individual videos to the so called "list"
        // You can change the JPanel "video" to an JScrollPanel and make the video list scrollable
        videos.add(new Video("Why choose mechanical keyboard?", 4975742, "Showing Tech 64",
                "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/5ce/my-keyboard-1241023.jpg"));
        videos.add(new Video("Ports explained", 9284573, "Showing Tech 64",
                "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/7ed/the-back-side-of-my-external-dvd-rom-1519905.jpg"));
        videos.add(new Video("Java 4 life. Here's why!", 7947173, "Showing Tech 64",
                "https://www.filecluster.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/java-logo.jpg"));
        videos.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 0, 8, 0), null));
        contentPane.add(videos, BorderLayout.EAST);
        // That was it, the magic, down below you see a class Video, look that up also

        // Nothing exciting, a demo video, just for the looks :)
        JPanel demoVideo = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout2 = new BoxLayout(demoVideo, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        demoVideo.setLayout(layout2);

        // Search bar
        JTextField search = new JTextField() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paint(g);
                if (getText().length() == 0) {
                    int h = getHeight();
                    ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                    Insets ins = getInsets();
                    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
                    int c0 = getBackground().getRGB();
                    int c1 = getForeground().getRGB();
                    int m = 0xfefefefe;
                    int c2 = ((c0 & m) >>> 1) + ((c1 & m) >>> 1);
                    g.setColor(new Color(c2, true));
                    g.drawString("Search anything", ins.left, h / 2 + fm.getAscent() / 2 - 2);
                }
            }
        };
        search.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        search.setBackground(new Color(192, 192, 192, 255));
        search.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        search.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8),
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.white)));
        contentPane.add(search, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Video
        demoVideo.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getImage("https://dclottery.com/img/play-button-overlay.png").
                getScaledInstance(640, 360, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH))));
        JPanel info = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(8, 8));

        // Title
        JLabel title = new JLabel("The art of lighting. Get professional");
        title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
        demoVideo.add(title);

        // Views
        JLabel views = new JLabel("8,195,384 views");
        views.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        demoVideo.add(views);

        // Author
        JLabel author = new JLabel(" Showing Tech 64 ");
        author.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
        author.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.lightGray));
        author.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 64));
        demoVideo.add(author);

        demoVideo.add(info);
        // Add gap around the content pane
        demoVideo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8), null));
        contentPane.add(demoVideo, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        // JFrame info
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static class Video extends JPanel {
        String name, author, imageURL;
        int views;
        BufferedImage image;

        public Video(String title, int views, String author, String imageURL) {
            super(new BorderLayout(8, 8));
            // Set the size of the video panel
            setMaximumSize(new Dimension(460, 96));
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(460, 96));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(460, 96));

            // Initialize variables, add your own if needed
            this.name = title;
            this.views = views;
            this.author = author;
            this.imageURL = imageURL;

            // Get image, remove it and pass the image directly as an argument if needed
            image = getImage(imageURL);

            // Add components, here's the magic
            JLabel thumbnail = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(170, 96, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
            thumbnail.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(170, 96));
            add(thumbnail, BorderLayout.WEST);

            JPanel info = new JPanel();
            BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(info, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
            info.setLayout(layout);

            JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel(makeWebSafe(title));
            titleLabel.setForeground(Color.black);
            titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
            titleLabel.setToolTipText(title);
            info.add(titleLabel);
            JLabel authorLabel = new JLabel(makeWebSafe(author));
            authorLabel.setForeground(Color.gray);
            authorLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 14));
            info.add(authorLabel);
            JLabel viewsTitle = new JLabel(makeWebSafe(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(views)+" views"));
            viewsTitle.setForeground(new Color(64, 128, 64));
            viewsTitle.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
            info.add(viewsTitle);

            add(info, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            // This is here to add a little gap between the videos in the list
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                    BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 2, 2, 2), null));
        }
    }

    // Inserting strings to an html without telling it, that it is not an piece of code, is very dangerous, use this method!
    // I used it to show the information about videos, because the name of the video might
    // contain html
    public static String makeWebSafe(String string) {
        return string.replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;");
    }

    // Download the image from the url, the image will not be stored as a file
    public static BufferedImage getImage(String imageURL) {
        try { return ImageIO.read(new URL(imageURL));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you can add `ActionListener` to the video container (the JPanel) to execute piece of code, when clicked on it, for example start the video. Add another `ActionListener` for the JLabel showing the author's name, to take the user to the author's page for example.